# Can index.html play an audio file? If so, How can I implement it to auto play in the back ground?

Tags: javascript, html

Ive tried this in my code and cant seem to make it work.

```
<body>
  <div id='container'>
    <canvas id='game' width='320' height='480'></canvas>
  </div>
  <p>HTML background music test</p>
     <embed src="music/alien-spaceship_daniel_simion.mp3" autostart="true">
  <script src='Scripts/engine.js'></script>
  <script src='Scripts/game.js'></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Browsers have started preventing auto play due to the annoyance

Comment: Would you happen to know of a workaround? It is for a open source game and would love for it to play music

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sorts of embeds are discouraged these days, as they are not supported on all systems.  Additionally, each plugin often had its own distinct API.  You should use an `<audio>` tag instead.

```
<audio src="music/alien-spaceship_daniel_simion.mp3" controls autoplay />
```

Note however that `autoplay` doesn't typically work anymore, thanks to excessive abuse of the feature, and [subsequent browser policies](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes).